# How to display a double digit decimal value on a seven segment display?

Tags: 7segmentdisplay

I recently finished a 4 bit adder project and I wanted to "extend" it.Right now,the output is represented by 4 led's(1 for each bit).I want to display the answer as a decimal in a seven segment display.The biggest value that the adder can output is 15(since it is a 4 bit adder).I have two single digit seven segment displays.I was thinking of using the 74ls47 chip to do the binary to seven seg conversion.Here is the datasheet for [BCD TO 7-SEGMENT CODER/DRIVER](http://freedatasheets.com/downloads/74LS47.pdf)

How do I check to see if the addition output is a double digit number?Using this information, how do I "tell" the binary to seven seg converter, that it is double digit?Do I need two of these chips?My final question is:the biggest decimal a single digit seven segment display can represent is 9. When the 74ls47 gets an input greater than this it starts display jibberish:( I got that information from [Using the 74xx47 BCD to Seven-segment display](http://ttp://www.davidswinscoe.com/electronics/components/7447/).

How would I prevent the jibberish from getting displayed(basically I need a way to check if the output of the addition is 10 or greater.)

Sorry about all the questions this is the first digital logic circuit that I have made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is convert the binary into something called BCD - Binary Coded Decimal.

Basically BCD is binary, but only takes the values 0-9 for each digit.

If you can still get hold of them (no idea if you can), there was a 7400 series IC that does the conversion. As I recall it was 74185.

Alternatively, if they are not available, you could use a parallel EEPROM IC or something like that. If you store the BCD equivalent values in addresses 0-15 of the EEPROM, then the lower 4 address bits become your 4bit binary input, then 5 of the bits of the data outputs can be your BCD value (the 5th bit being carry - i.e. 10).

---

Thinking about it, you could even use an 8-bit EEPROM to do the whole thing (including 7-segment). If you use the lower 7 bits for the first 7-segment, and the other data bit can go to segments B&C on the second 7-segment display. Again by storing the equivalent values in addresses 0-15 you can make a lookup table to generate the mapping.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a ROM but that's sort of cheating.

Another method is to detect when the number is >9 and add 0x6 to the number (you need to have another 4-bit adder). Then you will have 0..9 in the least significant digit and 1 or 0 in the most significant digit (if the number before the second adder is > 9 it is 1, otherwise 0).

Answer (score 2):

The out put above '9' is not jibberish, it is defined see the [74ls47 Data Sheet](http://home.agh.edu.pl/~ostrowsk/teksty/74ls47.pdf).  If you don't like the appearance there are other chips that will display 'A' 'b' 'C' 'd' 'E' 'F'.  give me a sec to find one. Here's one: [DM9368 Data Sheet](http://socrates.berkeley.edu/~phylabs/bsc/PDFFiles/DM9368.pdf).

Comment: what do you mean when you say 'A' 'b' 'C' 'd' 'E' 'F'.Sorry i'm a newbie when it comes to seven segment displays. I know that each letter represents one of the 7 led's of the display.But why did you capitalize some?

Comment: 'B' looks like an '8' & 'D' looks like an '0' on the 7 segment display. The other letters would be hard to display uniquely as lowercase.

Comment: @zack1544 If numbers are represented in a hexadecimal format the letters a to f are used to represent 10-15. The capitalistaion is how they are displayed given the constraints of a seven segment display. for example if uppercase 'B' was used it would be indistinguishable from '8' and the same with 'D' and'0'.

Comment: So should I use the Dm9368?

Comment: @zack1544, I think using the DM9368 would be the easiest/cheapest solution for any number less than or equal to 0xF (15).  Assuming you are learning electronics, this solution will also make everything easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Problem is the DM9368 is now obsolete and so you cannot order it from anywhere. Likewise for the similar MC14495. I cannot find a currently made 4bit to 7 segment chip that uses hex anywhere.